# Itertools product of list

Tags: python, iteration, product, python-itertools

I have found this fonction, but i don't want

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4]]
print list(product(*A))
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

I would like to have just that below in answer

```
[(1, 4),(2, 3)]
```

How can i do that please ?

In fact, i don't want to have a number at the same place in the original list in my final list.

I have made that :

```
def afficherListe(A):
n=len(A)
B=[]
for i in range (0,n,1):
    for j in range (0,n,1):
        if i!=j:
            B.append(A[i][j])
return B
```

But it doesn't work I have just [2,3] in answer...

Comment: At the end, for this exemple, i want to have [(1,4),(2,3)] but with my function "AfficherListe" i have just (2,3) and i don't know where i have made a mistake in my function...

Comment: `(2,3)` is the only pair that matches your stated condition. What you seem to want instead is all pairs `(x,y)` where the position of `x` in the original list differs from the position of `y` in the original list, not all pairs where both `x`,`y` differ from their original positions.

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what you are trying to do. For example, what should the output be if `A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`?

Comment: Okay man. That should be [[1,5,9],[1,6,8],[2,4,9],[2,6,7],[3,4,8],[3,5,7]]. Thanks.

Comment: My edited code returns that exactly. The key idea is that of a permutation of the index set rather than a product of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that perhaps you want to get all tuples consisting of 1 item from each column and each row, as in a determinant calculation. If so:

```
from itertools import permutations

def afficherListe(A):
    """A is a square matrix. Returns all tuples used in det(A)"""
    n = len(A)
    return [tuple(A[i][j] for i,j in enumerate(p)) for p in permutations(range(n))]

#tests:
A = [[1,2],[3,4]]
B = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(afficherListe(A))
print(afficherListe(B))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 3)]
[(1, 5, 9), (1, 6, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 6, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 5, 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[(a,b) for a in A[0] for b in A[1] if A[0].index(a)!=A[1].index(b)]
```

Input :

```
A = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Out put :

```
[(1, 4), (2, 3)]
```